# how to leverage embedded resources in ReferenceArrayInput and ReferenceArrayField so it doesn't make extra calls

Tags: admin-on-rest

if my server responds with results like those:

```
row = {
   id: value,
   name: value,
   height: value,
   categories: [{id: "1", name: "name 1" },{id: "2", name: "name 2"},{id: "3", name: "name 3"},{id: "4", name: "name 4"}]
}
```

how can I use this information to populate my `ReferenceArrayField` `ChipFields` without requiring extra calls against `/categories?filter={ids: [ ]}` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't support this scenario currently. In AOR, `categories` should be a distinct resource and the resource you're showing should only references the categories ids.

If you do have a distinct resource for categories, then your `restClient` should *cleanup* the resource referencing categories and only includes their ids

Comment: I don't understand why this isn't supported considering the performance implication behind making additional network requests.

Comment: @JosephPersie after searching Redux a bit it seems it works well with flattened data and it has big difficulties with hierarchical/ embedded data.. I bet this is why aor took that direction..  you can use a plugin like this: https://github.com/MhdSyrwan/aor-embedded-array but it doesn't work for single objects - it works only with arrays of objects even though I requested that here it seems out of scope for the creator: https://github.com/MhdSyrwan/aor-embedded-array/issues/5

Comment: @MichailMichailidis Thanks for the recommendation. I seem to have resolved the issue and have posted my finding in the github issue here:
https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest/issues/1662